# Calculate the commutator between the operator $S_z$ and the operator $S_x$ using the Dirac notation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, angular-momentum, operators

Calculate the commutator between the operator $S_z$ and the operator $S_x$ using the Dirac notation.

In standard matrix notation I proved the relation $[S_z,S_x]=ihS_y$

My attempt in Dirac Notation: $$
\hat S_z= \frac h 2|\uparrow\rangle \langle \uparrow| \, - \frac h 2 \,|\downarrow\rangle \langle \downarrow|
$$

$$
\hat S_x= \frac h 2|\uparrow\rangle \langle \uparrow| \, - \frac h 2 \,|\downarrow\rangle \langle \downarrow|
$$

Hence, [$\hat S_z$, $\hat S_x$] = $\hat S_z$$\hat S_x$-$\hat S_x$$\hat S_z$

However when I calculate this I obtain the following relation:

$\frac {h^2} 4[|\uparrow\rangle \langle \uparrow|+ |\downarrow\rangle \langle \downarrow|]$ - $\frac {h^2} 4[|\uparrow\rangle \langle \uparrow|+ |\downarrow\rangle \langle \downarrow|]$

Which does not seem to be correct. Could anyone please show me where I might be going wrong. 
My guess would be that my spectral decomposition of the operators is incorrect but I'm not sure.

Comment: Your $S_x$ is the same as $S_z$ which is wrong.

Comment: I figured that as the decomposition of two different Pauli matrices shouldn't have been the same. Could you show me the correct $S_x$ so that I can continue with my calculation of the commutator. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your $S_z$ is the same as $S_z$ which is wrong. So the commutator will be wrongfully zero. The correct form is
$$S_x=\frac{\hbar}{2}\bigg(|\uparrow\rangle\langle\downarrow|+|\downarrow\rangle\langle\uparrow|\bigg)$$

Comment: Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

You suffer from a typo in the definition of your operator $\hat{S}_x$, which should read as
\begin{align}
\hat{S}_x=\frac{\hbar}{2}(|\downarrow\rangle\langle\uparrow|+|\uparrow\rangle\langle\downarrow|).
\end{align}

If you now compute the commutator and collect the terms, you will obtain the correct result:

\begin{align}
[\hat{S}_z,\hat{S}_x]&=(\frac{\hbar}{2})^2(|\uparrow\rangle\langle\downarrow|-|\downarrow\rangle\langle\uparrow|
+|\uparrow\rangle\langle\downarrow|-|\downarrow\rangle\langle\uparrow|)\\
&=i\hbar\hat{S}_y
\end{align}

For further information, have a look at the wikipedia article for the Pauli matrices:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pauli_matrices#Physics